# Сохранение массива в iCloud

Tags: swift

Какие существуют способы сохранения массивов в iCloud? Что бы после удаления приложения с устройства, после синхронизации все данные появлялись заново.

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Сохраняете сериализованные данные, как обычный документ в iCloud. Единственная толком не описанная особенность - иногда, после удаления приложения, надо несколько раз повторить попытку чтения, т.к. данные могут быть загружены из облака не сразу.

Comment: Ну если подробнее, то нужно сохранить два пользовательских массива в облако так, чтобы при загрузке приложения с нового устройства эти массивы грузились из облака. И все это не используя iCloudkit